# Why does Apache Flume regex extractor accept only "1 digit" ?

Tags: regex, flume

I am using Apache Flume regex extractor interceptor with multiplexing channel selector. When I am trying to use regex "^ID:([0-9]+)," for filtering, only the events containing 1 digit, e.g. ID:4, are captured. Why are all the events containing more digits, e.g. ID:100, ignored?

Comment: Don't see any reason why your regex should fail. Maybe remove the parenthesis around [0-9]+. Alternatively, you could try `^ID:\d{1,}`

Comment: Thank you for your help and suggestions. Unfortunately, the problem persists :(

Comment: Then I'd try a really greed RegEx approach and make it less greedy over time. i.e start with `ID:\d*` and see, if that works. then replace `*`with `+`, add `^` and so on...